# LEFT JOIN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

tengo 3 tablas de las que estoy intentando recoger datos haciendo LEFT JOINS.

En la tabla de contacts tengo 2 tipos de contactos, personas y empresas cada una con su id única y otra asociativa.

Cuando ejecuto la query que dejo abajo me recoge y organiza los datos mas o menos bien pero me asocia todo lo que hay dentro de contacts_info a los contactos que corresponden a personas y no se como incluir 2 veces de la misma tabla.

Para explicarme mejor: Necesito seleccionar contacts_info.phone_number y asociarlo a person.phone_number y company.phone_number

```
SELECT
tasks.id,
tasks.id_type,
tasks.id_account,
tasks.id_contact,
tasks.id_contact_company,
tasks.id_user
tasks.date_added,
tasks.date_modified,
tasks.title,


contacts.id AS contact_id,
contacts.name,
contacts.job,
contacts.company,

contacts_info.address,
contacts_info.city,
contacts_info.state,
contacts_info.zipcode,
contacts_info.country_static_name,
contacts_info.email,
contacts_info.phone_number,
contacts_info.website

FROM
tasks

LEFT JOIN contacts
ON contacts.id = tasks.id_contact

LEFT JOIN contacts_info
ON contacts.id = contacts_info.id_contact

WHERE tasks.deleted = 0
```

Comment: El campo `company` de `contact` es el id de la empresa? tiene su correspondencia con `contact_info.id_contact`?

Answer (score 0):

Si el campo `company` de la tabla `contacts` es un ID de la empresa, y tiene correspondencia con una fila de la tabla `contact_info` entonces simplemente haces un `LEFT JOIN` adicional con la tabla `contact_info`

```
SELECT tasks.*,
       contacts.id AS contact_id,
       contacts.name,
       contacts.job,
       contacts.company,
       contact_person.phone_number
       contact_company.phone_number

FROM
tasks

LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = tasks.id_contact

LEFT JOIN contacts_info contact_person
       ON contacts.id = contact_person.id_contact

LEFT JOIN contacts_info contact_company  
       ON contacts.company = contact_company.id_contact

WHERE tasks.deleted = 0
```

Si acaso hay un campo `company_id` en tu tabla `contacts` entonces tienes que reemplazar ese campo por el que usé yo a falta de más información.